# How to rewrite *.php?queryString to *.php@queryString.html via htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

How to rewrite URLs like

***.php?queryString**

to

***.php@queryString.html**

via .htaccess file?

---

For example

viewforum.php?f=13423&start=54380934

should do a 301 redirect to

viewforum.php@f=13423&start=54380934.html

---

**So two things should happen for any URL that points to a *.php file:**

1. Append ".html"
2. Replace question mark "?" with "@" if the URL contains a query string

And this should be done with a SEO friendly [R=301] because the php files don't exist anymore and have been converted to static html files.

Help is very appreciated!

---

I tried to solve 2. like this:

```
# Limit rewrite to php files only
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$
# Replace question mark
RewriteRule ^(.*)?(.*)$ /$1@$2 [R=301]
```

But it does not work, it outputs always "@?" instead of only "@"

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your attempts.

Comment: You need to remember that `?` inside a regex is by default something different than the character itself, so you need to escape it if you want to match it as is. Also to be honest I do not quite understand the rewriting from `?` to `@` as this will break many tools/configuration (the query part in URL is by standard what follows `?`).

Comment: Background is I have to deal with a phpbb board that was transformed into a static html archive via wget which replaced all "?" with a "@" when creating local files (because Windows file system does not allow ? character) and then just appended ".html"

Comment: QueryString  isn't part of match in RewriteRule.  You need  to match against `%{QUERY_STRING}` 

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+ 
RewriteRule \.php$ %{REQUEST_URI}@%{QUERY_STRING}.html? [L,R]` should work.